# php artisan queue:flush does not flush the queues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue

Our log is blowing up due to non-stop retries by the queue workers despite having the retries set to 1 only. This is literally caused by 3 different failed job payloads that are being retried millions of times due to a fatal error.

1. Why aren't the queued jobs just failed after the 1st one as configured?
2. Why doesn't `php artisan queue:flush` actually flush the queues so it will stop retrying all jobs?

Queue is SQS based so I went into SQS and purged there and then restart the queue workers, but I would have expected the flush command and the retry setting to have done their jobs.

Answer (score 1):

**php artisan queue:flush** Will only clear failed jobs, not all jobs on the queue.

To clear all jobs on the queue, use **php artisan queue:clear**

Answer (score 0):

if
**Php artisan queue:work not working**

try this

***php artisan queue:work --force***

if

**php artisan queue:flush does not flush**

try this
**

- php artisan queue:clear

**